# Ask about rxjs' use of Obsevable distinct

Tags: rxjs, reactive

I want to know how to use Observable. 
What I want to do is duplicate deletion. The following sample 1 can be moved, but what I want to do is not this format, but how to cook when preparing an array in advance.

```
orgLayerDistinct(allList: LabelMasterExt[]) {
// Observable.of( allList ).distinct( );

// [sample 1] このサンプルは動くが好みの形式ではない。
// [sample 1] This sample works, but it's not a form of favorite.
Observable.of<Person>(
{ age: 4, name: 'Foo'},
{ age: 7, name: 'Bar'},
{ age: 5, name: 'Foo'},
{ age: 6, name: 'Foo'})
.distinct((p: Person) => p.name)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

// [sample 2 experimental] 配列を用意してある前提で利用したい。
// [sample 2 experimental] I would like to use an array on the assumption that it is prepared.
const persons: Person[] = [];
persons.push({ age: 4, name: 'Foo'});
persons.push({ age: 7, name: 'Bar'});
persons.push({ age: 5, name: 'Foo'});
persons.push({ age: 6, name: 'Foo'});
Observable.of<Person[]>(persons)
.distinct((p: Person) => p.name)
.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

}

[sample 2 experimental]
However, this gives the following error.

```
The type argument for type parameter 'T' cannot be inferred from the usage.
Consider specifying the type arguments explicitly.
Type argument candidate 'Person[]' is not a valid type argument
because it is not a supertype of candidate 'Person'.
Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Person'.
```

Is there any good plan?

Comment: You most likely want `Observable.from(persons)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `Observable.from<Person>(array)` or `Observable.of<Person>(...array)`.

The problem your second example has is that `Observable.of<Person[]>()`s elements are arrays of `Person`, but the `.distinct()` is expecting an input of the `Person` type.

Comment: Thank you, Ionut Costica. As you say, I found out that you can use 'Observable.from <Person> (array)'.